# Why is CartographerROS install stopping with this "Failed to find Ceres" error?

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin, ceres-solver

I am trying to install CartographerROS on Ubuntu 20.04.  I have installed ROS Noetic, and followed the instructions for installing CartographerROS here: https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compilation.html#building-installation

Everything worked fine until running catkin_make_isolated --install --use-ninja, which resulted in the following error:

CMake Error at /lib/cmake/Ceres/CeresConfig.cmake:88 (message): Failed to find Ceres - Ceres install root: /, determined from relative path from CeresConfig.cmake install location: /lib/cmake/Ceres, does not contain Ceres headers.  Either the install directory was deleted, or the install tree was only partially relocated outside of CMake after Ceres was built.  Call Stack (most recent call first): /lib/cmake/Ceres/CeresConfig.cmake:149 (ceres_report_not_found) CMakeLists.txt:39 (find_package)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (find_package): Found package configuration file:
/rib/cmake/Ceres/CeresConfig.cmake
but it set Ceres_FOUND to FALSE so package "Ceres" is considered to be NOT FOUND.

This is done on a new install of Ubuntu, and all I've done is install ROS, then try to install CartographerROS.  The strange part is this all worked when I installed CartographerROS about a month ago- has something about the Ceres build changed since then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the installer was looking in the wrong place for include files.  It was looking in /include for a folder that was actually in /usr/include, so I just made a link to that folder in the location where the installer was searching.

Comment: Could you explain how you made the link to /usr/include?